# How to add value of column to ggplot barchart on hover in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, ggplotly

Ii have a dataset called final_result with the colnames[1] "pathway"                               "genes_involved_in_pathway"             "kit_gene_counts"
[4] "leiomyo_lipo_gene_counts"              "nos_leiomyo_gene_counts"               "nos_lipo_gene_counts"
[7] "genes_leiomyo_lipo"                    "genes_nos_leiomyo"                     "genes_nos_lipo"
[10] "genes_leiomyo_lipo_commonly_expressed" "genes_nos_leiomyo_commonly_expressed"  "genes_nos_lipo_commonly_expressed"

```
gg <- ggplot(final_result, aes(x = reorder(pathway, -kit_gene_counts))) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = kit_gene_counts), stat = "identity", fill = "lightblue", width = 0.5) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = leiomyo_lipo_gene_counts), stat = "identity", fill = "orange", width = 0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(y = kit_gene_counts, label = kit_gene_counts), vjust = -0.2, color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(y = leiomyo_lipo_gene_counts, label = leiomyo_lipo_gene_counts), vjust = -0.2, color = 
 "black") +
  labs(title = "Concordance between Genes from Kit in Pathways and DGE genes Leiomyo Lipo", x = 
 "Pathway", y = "Number of Genes") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

I want for the blue bar on hover to appear **genes_leiomyo_lipo_commonly_expressed** value and for the orange bar on hover the **genes_leiomyo_lipo** value.  I tried different approaches none with the desired result.

This is the current result of the code above.

[image]

I tried with plotly different approaches but no results.

Comment: you might give {ggiraph} a try: https://www.ardata.fr/ggiraph-book/